# how to use python to login page which requires session id responded by server on first request?

Tags: python, session, request, session-cookies

I am writing a script to log in to some webpage. I using request and request.session module for this purpose.On first request with login parameters server responses a session id.How to set that session id for further login to same page.

```
url = "some url of login page"
payload = {'username': 'p05989', 'password': '123456'}
with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(url1, data=payload)
    sessionid = s.cookies.get('SESSIONID')
    print(sessionid)
    r = requests.get(url,data=payload)
    print(r.text)
```

in above code,
server responses sessionid on first request.How to use that sessionid on second request?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are already using `requests.session()`; it handles cookies for you, *provided you keep using the session* for all your requests:

```
url = "some url of login page"
payload = {'username': 'p05989', 'password': '123456'}
with requests.session() as s:
    # fetch the login page
    s.get(url)

    # post to the login form
    r = s.post(url1, data=payload)
    print(r.text)
```

You probably do first need to use `GET` to get the session id set before posting to the login form.

The `SESSIONID` cookie is handled transparently for you.

Comment: @Heisenberg: No, as long as you keep using `s` to do your requests, you do not have to worry about the cookie.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters : does get and post methods of session objects belongs to form methods?

Comment: @Heisenberg: A *browser* interprets the HTML to find form elements, and when you then submit the form the browser inspects the `<form>` tag to see what should happen and it'll use `GET` or `POST` as instructed. The `request.Session().post()` and `request.Session().get()` methods execute such `POST` or `GET` requests for you, just like `request.post()` and `request.get()` would do, but *with any cookies*.

Comment: thank you for your reply.But i dont understand that   my login form uses post method for submit.But you have written s.get() method in answer.will it work?

Comment: @Heisenberg: The first `.get()` just fetches the form *with the Set-Cookie header*. The `data=payload` parameter was an error there; it originated from your question code where you used `requests.get(url, data=payload)`.

Comment: :i checked session id both time with .get() and .post() using s.cookies ,both times it changes and i got unauthorised access page

Comment: @Heisenberg: That could be any number of reasons; the site could be filtering on specific headers (only allowing certain User-Agent values, for example), or the form includes a CSRF token you need to post too. That's not the fault of how you are using sessions here. Working out what exactly is too broad to post here in the comments. You want to do some research on this; there are plenty of questions here on Stack Overflow using `requests` to post login information to sites, for example.

Comment: @Martin Pieters: Thank you , I'ill go thorough those QAs.

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
import webbrowser

url = "https://www.invezta.com/investorsignup.aspx"


payload = {'login-email':  'email',
    'login-pwd': 'password'}

with requests.session() as s:
    # fetch the login page
    s.get(url)

    url1='https://www.invezta.com/Pdf_creator.aspx?User_ID='

    # post to the login form
    r = s.post(url1, data=payload)
    print(r.text)
```