# How to get the EXACT, REAL value of 'href'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a program that can fetch information about my attendance from my college website. In order to do that i wrote a script to login to the website ,which leads me to my dashboard ,and then go to the `Attendence` tab, get the `href` and attach it to `url` of the college website ,
the tag in the `attendence` class looked like this

`<a href="../Student/StudentAttendanceView.aspx?SID=7JyKkZE1Eyx2EYNii7tOjQ==|yaE7DmfR9r8=" id="aAttandance">Attendance</a>`

and when i clicked the attendance link the ,webpage had a `url` on the Address bar looked like this

`http://erp.college_name.edu/Student/StudentAttendanceView.aspx?SID=7JyKkZE1Eyx2EYNii7tOjQ==|yaE7DmfR9r8=` .

So, it was self explanatory that i was supposed to attach the `href` to the

`'http://erp.college_name.edu'` . Ok, i did i.e.

```
 L = 'http://erp.college_name.edu' + str(I.findAll('li')[4].a.get('href').replace('.', ''))
```

but the problem is that when i fetch the `href` it is something else than that in the tag, it keeps on changing and when i get the link that is when i print `L` i got this.. which i assumed to get..

`http://erp.college_name.edu/Student/StudentAttendanceViewaspx?SID=aDmK9cEFWwDqvsWw5ZzEOw==|oTeYVRfW1u8=`

but the problem is that the `href` i'm getting in is different from the real `url` , and IT KEEPS ON CHANGING WHEN I RE-RUN THE PROGRAM ,the second time i got

`http://erp.college_name.edu/Student/StudentAttendanceViewaspx?SID=WM/lbVRchyyBiLsDvkORJw==|MaP8NtvvrHE=`

, why i'm getting this ,and moreover when i click on other links on my Dashboard page and again click on attendance tab , the `href` value in the `url` again changed in the address bar? ..

so, after that when i did,

```
opens = requests.get(L)
soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(opens.text, 'lxml')
print(L)
```

i got this..

```
    C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe 
    C:/Users/HUNTER/PycharmProjects/dictionary/erp_1.py
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html><head><title>The page cannot be found</title>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
 <style type="text/css">
    BODY { font: 8pt/12pt verdana }
    H1 { font: 13pt/15pt verdana }
    H2 { font: 8pt/12pt verdana }
   A:link { color: red }
    A:visited { color: maroon }
 </style>
 </head><body><table border="0" cellspacing="10" width="500"><tr><td>
  <h1>The page cannot be found</h1>
  The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name 
 changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
 <hr/>
 <p>Please try the following:</p>
 <ul>
  <li>Make sure that the Web site address displayed in the address bar of 
your browser is spelled and formatted correctly.</li>
  <li>If you reached this page by clicking a link, contact
    the Web site administrator to alert them that the link is incorrectly 
   formatted.
    </li>
    <li>Click the <a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Back</a> button to 
 try 
   another link.</li>
     </ul>
       <h2>HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.<br/>Internet 
    Information 
   Services (IIS)</h2>
<hr/>
 <p>Technical Information (for support personnel)</p>
 <ul>
     <li>Go to <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
     linkid=8180">Microsoft 
       Product Support Services</a> and perform a title search for the words 
    <b>HTTP</b> and <b>404</b>.</li>
  <li>Open <b>IIS Help</b>, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr),
  and search for topics titled <b>Web Site Setup</b>, <b>Common 
   Administrative 
  Tasks</b>, and <b>About Custom Error Messages</b>.</li>
   </ul>
    </td></tr></table></body></html>


  Process finished with exit code 0
```

**UPDATE**

I replaced the `.replace('.', '')` method with `[2:]` because the the replace function also removed `.` from `.aspx` in the `href` and the problem now changed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871321/website-not-allowing-access-clicking-links-using-requests)

but still, how the value of `href` keep getting changed how can i fetch that page..

Any help?

Comment: Seems like this is a session ID they are using on the server. I'm sure if it's an attendance service there's some sort of user authentication going on, which means it's probably not something you can do simply with beautifulsoup. You need something that can simulate a headless browser and hold session cookies

Comment: so what do i need to do other than Beautifulsoup, and requests,can you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: A headless browser like selenium or phantomjs would be useful. Something that can store cookies for an authentication flow

Comment: Although on second thought you could try scaling it back a little and first try things like cookielib to store the cookies, I default to phantomjs too easily

Comment: can `Robobrowser` or `mechanicalSoup` can do the work? because i don't think `cookielib` is well suited for python 3.5.2

Comment: Seems like Robobrowser is a wrapper around both beautifulsoup and requests. I hadn't seen this before. You could first try using requests sessions since you're already using the requests library, and I think that'll have the same behavior as Robobrowser: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: problem isn't solved by `sessions()` either..

Comment: How are you using it? You shouldn't be using a function called `sessions()` like that. Rather you should be replacing your get call with a call from a Session object you instantiate. Are you doing that? Also since this conversation is getting pretty long, maybe we should consider moving it to chat.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22300308/4014959

Comment: did you figured anything by the code? what headers i need to add, i saw the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22300308/4014959) i have to add my login info i,e username and password ,but is there anything else i need to add