# Website not allowing access [clicking links using requests]

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to make goto a link (attendance link) on my dashboard page of my college ID, (after I made a script to login to the website, using requests).

I got the `href` of the link and attached it to the main URL of the webpage, i.e. the `href` looked like this:

`../Student/StudentAttendanceView.aspx?SID=d5ZJjDPElr2gLui0QuBhtA==|KfGEwXYb8QU=`

and the URL of the link on the address bar:

`http://erp.college_name.edu/Student/StudentAttendanceView.aspx?SID=d5ZJjDPElr2gLui0QuBhtA==|KfGEwXYb8QU=`

So after removing the two `..`s from the `href` I attached it to `http://erp.college_name.edu`.

The problem is that when I'm trying to fetch the `source-code-text` from the link, the website is not allowing me to do so, instead of the source code (of the attendance link page) I'm getting this:

```
ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center><img src="images/stop-sign-small2.jpg" /></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem? Why isn't the website allowing me to do so? I'm also parsing the headers on the time of login and some additional to it, but still the access is not possible:

This question is related to my earlier question of this same project [in case you want to relate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858967/how-to-get-the-exact-real-value-of-href). How can I fix this?

And the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://erp.college_name.edu/'

start = requests.session()
token = '3BA8C6EB'
token_1 = 'value'
stuff = {
    'tbUserName': 'my_usrname',
    'tbPassword': 'my_pass',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': ''.join(token),
    'btnLogIn': 'Login',
    '__VIEWSTATE' : ''.join(token_1),
}

new_stuff = {
             '__EVENTTARGET' : '',
             '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
             '__VIEWSTATE': 'value',
             'tbUserName': 'my_username',
             'tbPassword': 'my_pass',
             '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '791C70D1',
             'btnLogIn': 'Login',
            }

opens = start.post(url=url, data=stuff)
soup = BeautifulSoup(opens.text, 'lxml')

for I in soup.find_all('div', class_='lPanel'):
    L = 'http://erp.college_name.edu' + str(I.findAll('li')
    [4].a.get('href')
    [2:])
    attendance = start.get(url=L, headers=new_stuff, data=stuff)
    print(attendance)
```

Comment: Could you provide some code you've written? Also, you may use PhantomJS driver to simulate an actual user.

Comment: Have you actually tried to check if the page even exists? When I go to 
`http://erp.college_name.edu/Student/StudentAttendanceView.aspx?SID=d5ZJjDPElr2gLui0QuBhtA==|KfGEwXYb8QU=`, I get DNS error, domain name not known.

Comment: yea, i don't know why it showing that too, the `href` of the `Attendance` button keeps changing itself ,i don't know much about `html` but maybe the generate a new link on every request i have elaborated the problem in my earlier question of this project which is linked [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858967/how-to-get-the-exact-real-value-of-href)

Comment: Indentation is critical in Python. Is that the actual code that you have posted? If the original is pasted into a console with Python there are ***a lot of errors*** of this type: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`